# Initiating browser click works but causing bug

Tags: jquery, datatables

Basically I am using the DataTables plugin and it sorts the table rows on a table heading click. I need to reproduce this behavior when using a select option drop down. When u click once the table heading sorts the table rows in ascending order when you click again it sorts in descending order. I am using the code below to make the select option drop down initiate a click but if I click on the table heading not using the drop down it will not allow me to sort in descending order. If more explanation is needed please ask before you down vote.

```
$("select").change(function(){

    var searchInput = $("#searchInput");
    var oTable = $('table').dataTable();

    if($(this).val() == "1") {

        $(searchInput).val('');
        $("tbody tr").css("display", "");
        $('th:nth-child(3):first')[0].click();          

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "2") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "3") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "4") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "5") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(7):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(7):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "6") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(8):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(8):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "7") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(9):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(9):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "8") { 

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(10):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(10):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

    else if($(this).val() == "9") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function() {
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(11):not(:contains('"+searchInput.val()+"'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
                $("tbody tr td:nth-child(11):contains('"+searchInput.val()+"')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });     
    }

});



$('th:nth-child(3):first').click(function() {
    $('select').val(1).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(4):first').click(function() {
    $('select').val(2).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(5):first').click(function() {
    $('select').val(3).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(6):first').click(function() {
    $('select').val(4).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(7):first').click(function() {
    $('select').val(5).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(8):first').click(function() {
    $('select').val(6).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(1):last').click(function() {
    $('select').val(7).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(2):last').click(function() {
    $('select').val(8).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(3):last').click(function() {
    $('select').val(9).change();
});
```

Comment: _...but if I click on the table heading not using the drop down it will not allow me to sort in descending order_...
So, does your `select` work or not? And does clicking work?

Comment: That part is confusing... When you use the select you can make it do both ascending and descending as long as u change the option first. When you click the heading you can make it do ascending and descending. But when you use the select first and then try to click the heading to change ascending to descending it stays frozen at what the select option had chosen. make any sense?

Comment: My thoughts are that maybe the initiated click by the select is not being released...

Comment: I think I can help if you show me an example at jsFiddle maybe.

Comment: Your original problem description does not seem to match your posted code. It seems like what you are really trying to do is add a `SELECT` box that chooses which column will be searched when the user clicks the **Search** button. Can you please verify? And please insert either a Snippet ("Insert Snippet" icon from toolbar while editing your question), or a fiddle as http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start out by saying never write a function that triggers the action of an object. Your example is attempting to trigger a click event on a button vs simply calling a function. That being said you should make JSFiddle your best friend for javascript testing and questions. It would make your example much easier to read and test.

As @nothingisnecessary stated, you need to use the `fnSort()` function to update the table sorting. Below is a super cut and dry example given my limited time to answer this question.

[Datatable Sorting with Dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/mu7t4e4y/)

On a bit of a side note you should really try to avoid selectors outside of class and id. You only make your code a lot more complex and prone to bugs and you make it difficult for any developer that comes behind you to edit/test your code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't trigger the `click`; call `fnSort()` directly instead:

See http://datatables.net/api#fnSort

To wit:

```
$("select").change(function()
{
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  if ($(this).val() == "1")
  { 
    // Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
    oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
  }
});
```

Be sure to replace `'#example'` with the appropriate selector for your table object. (You didn't post the markup for this, otherwise I would have used your actual table ID).

Also, you can do this much more simply (and dynamically, which makes maintenance / enhancements easier) by genericizing it.  See this Working example: (click **Show Snippet** and then **Run** it)

```js
var $tblSortable = $("#tblSortable").dataTable();

function sortTable() {
  var direction = $("#tblSorterDir").val();
  var colIdx = +($("#tblSorter").val()) - 1; // coerce val string to number, convert to 0-based index
  $tblSortable.fnSort([
    [colIdx, direction]
  ]);
}
$("#tblSorter,#tblSorterDir").on("change", sortTable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></link>
<h3>
CHOOSE SORT COLUMN: 
  <select id='tblSorter'>
    <option value="1">Col 1</option>
    <option value="2">Col 2</option>
    <option value="3">Col 3</option>
  </select>
</h3>
<h3>
CHOOSE SORT DIRECTION: 
  <select id='tblSorterDir'>
    <option value="asc">ASC</option>
    <option value="desc">DESC</option>
  </select>
</h3>
<table id="tblSortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2-1</td>
      <td>2-2</td>
      <td>2-3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is causing the same issue.

Comment: I added more of my jQuery if it helps.